# Adding data to a DB table with Linq to Entities (EDMX) if the table doesn't have a primary key?

Tags: .net, sql, linq-to-entities, edmx

I'm attempting to add data to a table and linq to entities throws an excpetion with:

> Unable to update the EntitySet 'XXXX' because it has a DefiningQuery
>   and no  element exists in the
>    element to support the current
>   operation.

The table I'm trying to add data has no primary key and if I add a column of int and set it as primary key, the problem goes away, but in a purist/OCD sense, this column is not necessary

```
UserTable      UserGroup               GroupTable
ID Name        UserId GroupId          ID Name
```

Does adding data to a DB table with Linq to Entities (EDMX) require that the table have a primary key?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can manually edit the generated `.edmx` file, look for Error strings and correct them. It turns out that EF does need a primary key for every table (which is not a many-to-many relationship).

More on tables without primary keys and why it is considered wrong to EF: http://www.i-think22.net/archives/2009/07/24/linq-to-sql-and-tables-with-no-primary-key/